# SP Online 2013 blog: jslink change to "created by" field corrupts comments list

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, blog, jslink

I'm replacing the "created by" field in a blog posts list with a custom user defined "author" field using a simple jslink script. This works fine but when a user posts a comment, the jslink change appears to get carried over to the comments list and since there's no "author" field present, returns "undefined".

```
(function () {

var overrideCtx = {};

overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {'Author':{'View':CBody}};        

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function CBody(ctx) {

var ret = "<span >" + ctx.CurrentItem.Author0 + " </span>" 


return ret;

}
```

Comment: Put a undefined check on Author Field.

Comment: What about hidding the created by instead of replacing it completely? and if Author is undefined you can show the Created by

Comment: @AmalHashim can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you post relevant code?

Comment: @yngrdyn that might be a good idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added jslink code to question...

Answer (score 3):

By *when a user posts a comment*, you probably mean that user is located on the page `Post.aspx`, right?

Assume the custom field `PostAuthor` have to be displayed instead of standard `Author` field in blog page and the following template is used for that purpose:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      Templates: {
           Fields: {
               "Author": {
                   View: renderPostAuthor
               }
           }
      },

      ListTemplateType: 301,

    });

});


function renderPostAuthor(cxt) {
  return "<span >" + ctx.CurrentItem.PostAuthor[0].title + " </span>";
}
```

In order to display additional field on `Posts.aspx` page,  the view that is rendered on this page need to modified, in particular custom field have to be added into the view.

Since the view that is rendered on `Post.aspx` page is *hidden* the following example demonstrates how to add field into view (`PostAuthor` in my case) using CSOM API:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{     
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Posts");
     var result = ctx.LoadQuery(list.Views.Where(v => v.BaseViewId == "7"));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     var views = result.ToList();
     if (views.Count > 0)
     {
         var view = views[0];
         view.ViewFields.Add("PostAuthor");
         view.Update();
         ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      }
}
```

Once the view is updated and template is applied the blog page might look like this:

[image]

Comment: I can add the custom author field to a blog post using a script called by jslink without issue. That works but then somehow breaks the Author field in the comments list. I assume the script I'm using gets attached to both the posts and comments list due to a faulty design.

Comment: Hi, I tried above solution and when I am running ctx.CurrentItem.PostAuthor[0].title on console it is giving proper output. but when i am using same ctx.CurrentItem.PostAuthor[0].title in JSLink, I am getting [object Object]. why?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function CBody(ctx) {
    if(ctx.CurrentItem.hasOwnProperty("Author0") && ctx.CurrentItem.Author0 != undefined) {
        var ret = "<span >" + ctx.CurrentItem.Author0 + " </span>" 
        return ret;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that gives me "[object Object]undefined 
[object Object]undefined"....

Comment: Correction - that shows correctly in post, but nothing in comments list. (Author is empty).

Comment: Try my edited answer.

Comment: No luck....I should be adding this to the posts not the comments list, right?